# How do I link to the particular ID of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a search controller and index page:

```
# search/index.html.erb

<% @user_prices.each do |up| %>
   # This needs to go to particular ID of UserPrice.
   <%= link_to show_user_price_path do %>
        <%= up.product_name %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>

----------------------------------------------------------
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @search = UserPrice.search do
      fulltext params[:search]
      paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
    end
    @user_prices = @search.results
  end
end
```

Above you can see on my search form I am trying to link the product name to that particular UserPrice.How would I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure why you're using the block form of `link_to`, if you check the [link_to documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) there is an easier way to use the function to get what you want.

```
<% @user_prices.each do |up| %>
  <%= link_to up.product_name, show_user_price_path(up) %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= link_to up.product_name, show_user_price_path(up) %>
```

That should do?